# Create a ResourceModel based on 3rd Party API Call from Magento

Tags: magento2.3, grid, rest-api, resource-model

I am working on integrating a 3rd Party API into Magento. I'd like to use an Admin Grid with a Data Source that comes from a 3rd party API. So Essentially the Flow work like this...
User Loads into admin page with grid -> grid has data source specified to resource model -> resource model calls 3rd party api to get data -> data is returned to resource model(not sure if its supposed to be resource model or collection or factory in this scenario) -> data is bind through the resource model to the grid.

If there's any additional information needed please let me know. I'm not sure what all information might be helpful.

Comment: There is a simple way and imho, a better way to do this. You create a cron to constantly pull data into your database and then make use of that data as normal grid

Answer (score 0):

I have never implemented a kind of complex integration like that, but I think you can base your code to the ElasticSearch connection. I know that you are working on Magento 2.3, and I do not remember which version of Magento require ES as default service, but even if you do not have the ES library you can analyze how it works here:

`https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/blob/2.10.x/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Fulltext/Collection.php`

But firstly, you can try to check it locally:

`vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Fulltext/Collection.php`

That collection extends Magento catalog collection but reimplement part of the code to access the ES API.

Collections have a bunch of methods that you will have to implement. It will not be an easy task.

Good Luck

Comment: would you have any recommendations on how to get data into a Magento grid from a 3rd party API? Just curious if I’m over complicating this or not!